# Cannot convert URL "..jks" to a file android

Tags: android, gradle

I am having hard time solving this error. Basically I imported muPDF source code from github which gave me this bug. Here is the build.gradle and the error:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'

    }

}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}

Error:(6, 0) Cannot convert URL 'D:/Projects/PDF/Mupdf/mupdf_release_key.jks' to a file.
```

I am using Mac not windows so the addresspath is incorrect.
I am working on a project which requires this. Please help me with this bug. I have checked almost all related questions and nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Post the line in your build.gradle where the jks is used

Answer (score 6):

Change these paths in build.gradle to correct file on your filesystem:

[Line 6](https://github.com/archko/Mupdf/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L6)

```
storeFile file('D:/Projects/PDF/Mupdf/mupdf_release_key.jks')
```

[Line 11](https://github.com/archko/Mupdf/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L11)

```
storeFile file('D:/Projects/PDF/Mupdf/mupdf_release_key.jks')
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this `D:/Projects/PDF/Mupdf/mupdf_release_key.jks`

to

`clovis@Cloviss-MacBook-Pro/Projects/PDF/Mupdf/mupdf_release_key.jks`

This `clovis@Cloviss-MacBook-Pro` is the first entry you see when you open your terminal